# Render column partially in Kendo-grid

Tags: javascript, java, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to render grid partially using kendo Grid?
I have a grid with total columns > 200. This makes the rendering of the page really slow even though there's no data yet in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a way to limit the columns themselves (unlike rows) and generally there isn't really a use-case. 200 columns for a user are rather overwhelming and unhelpful (no one will ever look at them all).

The better strategy would be to limit the number of columns, and maybe offer multiple tables/views that may show the same data differently, or allow the user to click on a row to see the full columns of that item and that item alone.